# RStudio Server says rsession-which-r is an unrecognised option

Tags: r, debian, rstudio-server

I'm struggling with getting `rstudio-server` to connect to R (`rsession`) on Debian.

I'm launching it as a non-root user. It says, among other things, that `rsession-which-r` is an unrecognized option:

```
[rsession-jdm] ERROR system error 2 (No such file or directory) [path=/etc/sysconfig/i18n]; OCCURRED AT: core::Error core::FilePath::open_r(boost::shared_ptr<std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >*) const /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/core/FilePath.cpp:973; LOGGED FROM: void<unnamed>::ensureLang() /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/session/SessionMain.cpp:2764
02 Apr 2015 01:42:18 [rsession-jdm] ERROR system error 2 (No such file or directory) [path=/etc/locale.conf]; OCCURRED AT: core::Error core::FilePath::open_r(boost::shared_ptr<std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >*) const /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/core/FilePath.cpp:973; LOGGED FROM: void<unnamed>::ensureLang() /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/session/SessionMain.cpp:2764
02 Apr 2015 01:42:18 [rsession-jdm] ERROR system error 2 (No such file or directory) [path=/etc/sysconfig/language]; OCCURRED AT: core::Error core::FilePath::open_r(boost::shared_ptr<std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> > >*) const /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/core/FilePath.cpp:973; LOGGED FROM: void<unnamed>::ensureLang() /home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/session/SessionMain.cpp:2764
Error reading /etc/rstudio/rsession.conf: unrecognised option 'rsession-which-r'
```

R works fine on the CLI and I can see that `rstudio-server` is running tho it doesn't actually connect to R.

I've also tried adding this option in `rserver.conf` instead of `rsession.conf`

Answer (score 2):

It needs be set in the rserver.conf file, not the rsession.conf file. After changing it, restart the rstudio-server service and you should be good to go.